# Removing Effects from a textbox when effect is set on parent

Tags: c#, wpf, effect

I have a textbox in which one of the parent has a drop down shadow. I want to remove it from code since the effect is lousy as you can see in the pic:[image]

so when creating and adding the textbox I tried

```
Effect = null
Style = null
```

but the drowdown shadow is still there.